# Conversion a web-app to mobile-apps

Tags: mobile-application

There are several such services on the Internet which can cinvert a given web-page to a mobile application (Android, WP, BB, probably iOS).

Those services looks very attactive from reducing development time point of view but in the same time they looks very suspicious for me.

Does anyone have any experience with converting web-application to mobile? Is the result consistent?

Answer (score 0):

There are frameworks that can build mobile applications with HTML, CSS & JavaScript. The most famous is PhoneGap and also there are others like Ratchet. They can provide a set of JavaScript APIs that connect to the device’s native functions such as Camera, Compass, Contacts, and Geolocation. As an example with PhoneGap you can build applications for iOS, Android, Blackberry, WebOS, Symbian and Windows Mobile. As mentioned in wikipedia:

> It enables software programmers to build applications for mobile devices using JavaScript, HTML5, and CSS3, instead of relying on platform-specific APIs like those in iOS, Windows Phone, or Android. It enables wrapping up of HTML, CSS and Javascript code depending upon the platform of the device.

You can look here for list of the frameworks : http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/mobile-frameworks/. Although these frameworks help you develop mobile applications and require only webdev knowledge, that applications will not be as well as native ones.